# Password Reset Custom Validation Message

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using In-built reset password of django. Now the problem is that when i enter a email which does not exists in database, It does not give error that email does not exist. How can i give Validation In Django Reset Password. If email does not exist in auth_table

```
 # Reset Password
path('password-reset/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
         template_name='commons/password_reset/password_reset.html'
     ),
     name='password_reset'),
path('password-reset/done/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
         template_name='commons/password_reset/password_reset_done.html'
     ),
     name='password_reset_done'),
path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
         template_name='commons/password_reset/password_reset_confirm.html'
     ),
     name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('password-reset-complete/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
         template_name='commons/password_reset/password_reset_complete.html'
     ),
     name='password_reset_complete'),
```

Comment: basically django reset-password don't give any error message for email not exists

Comment: you need to customize django core reset-password to add email not exists error

Comment: Can i make custom error

Comment: check the below answer

Comment: From a security standpoint, you should not tell the user that the email does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

In forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm

class CustomEmailValidationOnForgotPassword(PasswordResetForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        email_id = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if not User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email_id, is_active=True).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Email invalid!")

        return email
```

And in urls.py

```
url(r'^password-reset/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset',
    {'post_reset_redirect': '/user/password/reset/done/',
     'html_email_template_name': 'registration/password_reset_email.html',
     'password_reset_form': CustomEmailValidationOnForgotPassword},
    name="password_reset"),
```

Hope it help's

for more details follow this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView)

Comment: I'm trying to understand how Django works. Where is the `clean_email` method called? If I'm customizing forms like `PasswordResetForm` how do I know how to call new methods I add?

Answer (score 0):

In the forms, return email_id.

```
def clean_email(self):
    email_id = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if not User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email_id, is_active=True).exists():
        raise ValidationError("Email Invalido! Usuario Inactivo o Inexistente")
    return email_id
```

This works very well for me.